# Threads waiting but why?

Tags: java, performance

I've got a thread dump from Eclipse where I can't explain what is happening. 
actually a lot of threads are waiting on 0x00000007a1ce4e60 (see dump below), but there is no thread really holding the lock and doing some work. 
Anyone has an explanation for this?

----edit--
It seems I did not clearly ask this question. 
if you check the dump below Worker 9 is waiting on 0x00000007a1ce4e60. I would have expected that there would be some other thread holding the lock with this id (there are) and this thread would do some work (it would not wait for this lock). But that does not seem to be the case.

--------dump---

dump for 10556
2014-07-11 14:51:59
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.12-b01 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5b4001000 nid=0x298a waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe584001000 nid=0x2979 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a0113000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000079bcb34e8> (a org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:106)
    - locked <0x000000079bcb34e8> (a org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor)

"org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e068c800 nid=0x296b in Object.wait() [0x00007fe552432000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000079ad85d40> (a org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.DirtyRegionQueue)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:179)
    - locked <0x000000079ad85d40> (a org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.DirtyRegionQueue)

"323468318@qtp-1324065911-1 - Acceptor0 SocketConnector@127.0.0.1:51235" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe57801f800 nid=0x296a runnable [0x00007fe552533000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <0x000000079ae707e8> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.accept(SocketConnector.java:99)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:707)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

"1848818517@qtp-1324065911-0" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe578036000 nid=0x2969 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe552634000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000079ae6fe58> (a org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    - locked <0x000000079ae6fe58> (a org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread)

"Worker-12" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe564012800 nid=0x2968 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe55283c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"Worker-11" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe57003f000 nid=0x2967 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe55293d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007a1ce4e60> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.waitForRun(ThreadJob.java:272)
    - locked <0x00000007a1ce4e60> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.joinRun(ThreadJob.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.begin(ImplicitJobs.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.beginRule(JobManager.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkManager.checkIn(WorkManager.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.prepareOperation(Workspace.java:2282)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1655)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.refresh.RefreshJob.runInWorkspace(RefreshJob.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

"Worker-10" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe564005000 nid=0x2966 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe552a3e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"Worker-9" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe560010800 nid=0x2965 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe552b3e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007a1ce4e60> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.waitForRun(ThreadJob.java:272)
    - locked <0x00000007a1ce4e60> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.joinRun(ThreadJob.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.begin(ImplicitJobs.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.beginRule(JobManager.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkManager.checkIn(WorkManager.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.prepareOperation(Workspace.java:2282)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Synchronizer.setSyncInfo(Synchronizer.java:225)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.SynchronizerSyncInfoCache$SyncInfoSynchronizedAccessor.internalSetCachedSyncBytes(SynchronizerSyncInfoCache.java:226)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.SynchronizerSyncInfoCache.setCachedSyncBytes(SynchronizerSyncInfoCache.java:146)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.SynchronizerSyncInfoCache.addStatus(SynchronizerSyncInfoCache.java:73)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.StatusCacheManager.updateCache(StatusCacheManager.java:121)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.StatusCacheManager.updateCache(StatusCacheManager.java:96)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.StatusCacheManager.setStatuses(StatusCacheManager.java:243)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.StatusCacheManager.basicGetStatus(StatusCacheManager.java:223)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.StatusCacheManager.getStatus(StatusCacheManager.java:194)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.StatusCacheManager.getStatus(StatusCacheManager.java:138)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.sync.SVNWorkspaceSubscriber.getSyncInfo(SVNWorkspaceSubscriber.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.subscribers.Subscriber.getDiff(Subscriber.java:371)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.mapping.SubclipseSubscriberChangeSetManager.getDiff(SubclipseSubscriberChangeSetManager.java:315)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.mapping.SubclipseSubscriberChangeSetManager$EventHandler.handleChange(SubclipseSubscriberChangeSetManager.java:196)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.mapping.SubclipseSubscriberChangeSetManager$EventHandler.doDispatchEvents(SubclipseSubscriberChangeSetManager.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.core.BackgroundEventHandler.dispatchEvents(BackgroundEventHandler.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.core.BackgroundEventHandler.processEvents(BackgroundEventHandler.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.core.BackgroundEventHandler$1.run(BackgroundEventHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

"Worker-8" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe55800b000 nid=0x2964 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe552c40000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"Worker-7" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe54c001000 nid=0x2963 waiting on condition [0x00007fe552d41000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager$1$ProgressJob.run(JobManager.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

"Worker-6" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe590024000 nid=0x2962 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe552e42000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"Worker-5" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe590023800 nid=0x2961 waiting on condition [0x00007fe552f43000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000079ae19d50> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.internal.gathering.services.UsageDataService.getQueuedEvent(UsageDataService.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.internal.gathering.services.UsageDataService.access$0(UsageDataService.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.internal.gathering.services.UsageDataService$1.run(UsageDataService.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

"Worker-4" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe590011800 nid=0x2960 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe568143000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007a1ce4e60> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.waitForRun(ThreadJob.java:272)
    - locked <0x00000007a1ce4e60> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.joinRun(ThreadJob.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.begin(ImplicitJobs.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.beginRule(JobManager.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ContentTypeDecorator.decorate(ContentTypeDecorator.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

"Worker-3" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe580002000 nid=0x295f in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a0835000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007a1ce4e60> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.waitForRun(ThreadJob.java:272)
    - locked <0x00000007a1ce4e60> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ThreadJob.joinRun(ThreadJob.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.ImplicitJobs.begin(ImplicitJobs.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.beginRule(JobManager.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider.lockDocument(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider.readDocument(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.editors.quickdiff.LastSaveReferenceProvider.getReference(LastSaveReferenceProvider.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.texteditor.quickdiff.DocumentLineDiffer$2.run(DocumentLineDiffer.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

"Worker-2" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe580001000 nid=0x295e runnable [0x00007fe5a2289000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.canWrite(File.java:713)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resources.LocalResourceStatus.(LocalResourceStatus.java:88)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.StatusCacheManager.updateCache(StatusCacheManager.java:121)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.StatusCacheManager.updateCache(StatusCacheManager.java:96)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.status.StatusCacheManager.refreshStatus(StatusCacheManager.java:270)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resourcesListeners.FileModificationManager.refreshStatus(FileModificationManager.java:249)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resourcesListeners.FileModificationManager.access$2(FileModificationManager.java:222)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.resourcesListeners.FileModificationManager$2.run(FileModificationManager.java:187)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.util.JobUtility$1$1.run(JobUtility.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.util.JobUtility$1.run(JobUtility.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

"org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e0f26000 nid=0x295a in Object.wait() [0x00007fe56bffe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000079a8321f0> (a org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.DirtyRegionQueue)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:179)
    - locked <0x000000079a8321f0> (a org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.DirtyRegionQueue)

"Java indexing" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e0de4800 nid=0x2959 runnable [0x00007fe5a0213000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Scanner.getLineEnds(Scanner.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.problemReporter(Parser.java:10267)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.JavadocParser.updateDocComment(JavadocParser.java:881)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.AbstractCommentParser.commentParse(AbstractCommentParser.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.JavadocParser.checkDeprecation(JavadocParser.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.checkComment(SourceElementParser.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeModifiers(Parser.java:4881)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeRule(Parser.java:6415)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9652)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9889)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9846)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.parseCompilationUnit(SourceElementParser.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.SourceIndexer.indexDocument(SourceIndexer.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.indexDocument(JavaSearchParticipant.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager.indexDocument(IndexManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.indexing.IndexManager$1.execute(IndexManager.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:405)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"TeamCity remainder" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e062d800 nid=0x2957 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a0936000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000079abe6920> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
    - locked <0x000000079abe6920> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

"Activation listener" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e06aa800 nid=0x2956 runnable [0x00007fe5a0a61000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    - locked <0x0000000792083d50> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.activation.HttpActivationServer.run(HttpActivationServer.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"Dispatcher-Thread-2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e04b9800 nid=0x2955 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a0b65000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000079abe3930> (a org.apache.log4j.helpers.BoundedFIFO)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.log4j.Dispatcher.run(AsyncAppender.java:312)
    - locked <0x000000079abe3930> (a org.apache.log4j.helpers.BoundedFIFO)

"Worker-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe57c001000 nid=0x2954 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a0d47000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"Worker-0" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e0443000 nid=0x2953 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a0e48000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.sleep(WorkerPool.java:188)
    - locked <0x0000000799ce6ae8> (a org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.startJob(WorkerPool.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:50)

"Worker-JM" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe59809a000 nid=0x2951 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a2087000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000079232c108> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.InternalWorker.run(InternalWorker.java:58)
    - locked <0x000000079232c108> (a java.util.ArrayList)

"[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe59804c800 nid=0x2950 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a2188000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000792084a48> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.timer.TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:141)
    - locked <0x0000000792084a48> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe598008000 nid=0x294d in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a238a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000792084bb0> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <0x0000000792084bb0> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e07db000 nid=0x294c in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a248b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000791e99a00> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <0x0000000791e99a00> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"Bundle File Closer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e080b800 nid=0x294b in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a25bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000792084f30> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
    - locked <0x0000000792084f30> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)

"Framework Active Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e0321000 nid=0x294a in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5a28bb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000798fe5830> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.run(Framework.java:1817)
    - locked <0x0000000798fe5830> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e00b8000 nid=0x2948 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e00b5800 nid=0x2947 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e00b2800 nid=0x2946 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e00b0800 nid=0x2945 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e0093800 nid=0x2944 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5cfcfb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007920ec458> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <0x00000007920ec458> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e0091800 nid=0x2943 in Object.wait() [0x00007fe5cfdfc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007920ec3f0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000007920ec3f0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e0006000 nid=0x293d runnable [0x00007fe5e4b58000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.Call(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sleep(Display.java:4069)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopIdle(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopIdle(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:917)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2702)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e008b000 nid=0x2942 runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e0019000 nid=0x293e runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e001b000 nid=0x293f runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e001c800 nid=0x2940 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e001e800 nid=0x2941 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5e00c2800 nid=0x2949 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 1772

dump for 10654

Comment: Why shouldn't they wait? Would you rather they just left?

Comment: What do you need an explanation for? Please state what is the problem you are analyzing? Do you experience a performance issue? Does Eclipse hang? Please list the symptoms you want explained. (Because, as Peter says in his answer, the worker pools and other things in Eclipse are just there, waiting for something to do ...)

Answer (score 3):

Most of the thread are idle. They are waiting for something to do.

The only thread which appears to be doing anything is the "Java indexing" and this could be blocking operations which need to use the file system.

Comment: actually Worker-9 does some work, and it runs for a very long time. 
("svn status cache update" in the Eclipse UI) and I was wondering whether it would be slowed down by some contention with other threads.

Comment: @kohlerm if it's not slowed down by the network, it will be slowed down by your disk speed. e.g. do you have a HDD and a large number of files? ;) If it was CPU bound, and you had only one CPU then other threads might make a difference, but I doubt this is the case.

Comment: I have an SSD. It might be mostly CPU bound because it uses one CPU (but not fully). Still I was wondering why the thread dump seems to indicate that it is waiting on a lock and not just waiting for some IO to be finished.

Comment: @kohlerm it could be holding a lock while waiting for IO.